# Remove possible sequences from a string using regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of strings, some (not all) that have endings like:

```
"StringSignOut"
"String Sign Out"
"String SIGNOUT"
"StringSO"
"String SO"
"String S.O."
"StringS.O."
```

I want to get rid of all the sign outs and SOs, I'm just not sure how to do the pattern.

```
    private static String getGroup(String s, String pat, int g) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pat);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if (m.matches()) {
            return m.toMatchResult().group(g);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you post the expected output?

Comment: I'd want all of those above to just be "String".

Comment: Is sign out, SO, etc. guaranteed to be at the end of the `String`? Also, are you using "String" as a placeholder for real data?

Comment: Not guaranteed, just the majority of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this :

```
(?:\s*Sign\s*Out|\s*S\W?O\W?)
```

demo here : 
http://regex101.com/r/lX0dI5/3

Comment: The OP notes that `SignOut`, `S.O.`, etc. are not always at the end of the strings. This will fail to function in that circumstance. http://regex101.com/r/lX0dI5/2

Comment: Sir, so kind of you pointing that out. I will remove the $ from the end so that it starts working for your scenario too.

Comment: Yep! and +1 for the nifty tool you linked there.

Comment: This works quite well! But I had a couple not work (SANDPIPE SIGN OUT, Lavoy Sign out, AtlasTruckingS.o.). I tried `String companyName = line.replaceAll("(?i)(?:\\s*Sign\\s*Out|\\s*S\\W?O\\W?)", "");` to make it case insensitive, but then my poor string called "Sore Sign Out" becomes "re". Any ideas?

Comment: I ended up doing `line = line.replaceAll("(?i)(?:\\s*Sign\\s*Out)", ""); String companyName = line.replaceAll("(\\s*S\\W?O\\W?)", "");` because I wasn't sure how to only make the "Sign Out" portion case insensitive. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex with multiple selection to remove the `SO/signout` from the String

**sample:**

```
 String [] s = {    "StringSignOut",
                         "String Sign Out",
                         "String SIGNOUT",
                         "StringSO",
                         "String SO",
                         "String S.O.",
                         "StringS.O."};
     for(String s2 : s)
     {
         System.out.println(s2.replaceAll("SignOut| Sign Out| SIGNOUT|SO| SO| S.O.|S.O.", ""));
     }
```

**result:**

```
String
String
String
String
String
String
String
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below code,

```
String [] s = {    "StringSignOut",
             "String Sign Out",
             "String SIGNOUT",
             "StringSO",
             "String SO",
             "String S.O.",
             "StringS.O."};
   for(String s2 : s)
     {
    System.out.println(s2.replaceAll("(?i)\\s*(?:sign\\s*out|s\\W*o\\W*)", ""));
    }
```

**Output:**

```
String
String
String
String
String
String
String
```

**Pattern Explanation:**

- `(?i)` Case-insensitive modifier.
- `\s*` Matches zero or more space characters.
- `(?:...)` Non-capturing group.
- `sign\s*out` Matches the string sign followed by zero or more spaces and again followed by the string `out`.
- `|` Logical OR operator.
- `s\W*o\W*` Matches the string which has a literal `s` followed by zero or more non-word characters again followed by a literal `o` followed by zero or more non-word characters.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    String[] strings = new String[] {"StringSignOut","String Sign Out","String SIGNOUT","StringSO","String SO","String S.O."};
    for(String str : strings)
    {
        System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(?i)(sign\\s*out)|(s\\.?o\\.?)",""));
    }
```

Yields:

```
String
String 
String 
String
String 
String
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String[] arr = {"StringSignOut", "String Sign Out", "String SIGNOUT", "StringSO", "String SO", "String S.O.", "StringS.O."};

    String[] replace = {"SO", "SignOut", "Sign Out", "SIGNOUT", "S.O."};
    for (String s : arr) {
        String tmp = s;
        for (String rep: replace) {
            tmp = tmp.replace(rep, "");
        }
        System.out.println(tmp);
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
String
String 
String 
String
String 
String 
String
```